# Get IP addresses of network devices

Tags: mac, wireless-networking

How do I get the IP address of all the devices on my local network? I am using Mac OS X Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **nmap**, you can see machines that are alive and it will return both hostnames (if found) and IP addresses:

For example, if your network is 192.168.1.X, use:

```
nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24
```

or if it's 192.168.0.X:

```
nmap -sP 192.168.0.0/24
```

**Example output:**

```
Host somedummyhost (192.168.1.22) is up (0.0040s latency).
Host atinylaptop (192.168.1.32) is up (0.013s latency).
Host 192.168.1.44 is up (0.00019s latency).
Host 192.168.1.58 is up (0.020s latency).
Host 192.168.1.70 is up (0.018s latency).
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (5 hosts up) scanned in 11.63 seconds
```

Comment: However, the wireless router may be configured to prevent clients talking to each other.  In this case you see only the router and yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Why bother downloading and installing nmap?
If you are on a 192.168.1.xxx home network just ping 192.168.1.255 and look at the replies. All the devices on your subnet that can respond to the ping will. you can arp -a for additional info.

Comment: This doesn't always work. I get no responses to `ping 10.1.1.255`. `ping 10.1.1.1` works fine, so I think some switches may block `ICMP ECHO` messages to the broadcast address.
(Yes, I'm using the `10.x.x.x` subnet.)

Comment: you need to ping your ip address with 255 in for the zero in the subnet mask. a 10.x.x.x network would be 10.255.255.255

Answer (score 0):

You could (and this is what I would do) run a [nmap](http://nmap.org/) scan on the local ip address range (e.g. 192.168.XXX.0-255) and see what responds.